# Building executable Program from c program

Tags: c, exe, executable, codeblocks

I used Code Blocks to generate an exe file from c program. When I open the exe file it opens normally and shows some text that I included in program. But if I give values to program and hit enter it will close automatically. It works fine if I run the program I Code Blocks.

Tell me is there any way building executable that runs fine in window or not? 
Your kind reply will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pause the system after execution of programm.

Either use:

```
system("pause");
```

or

```
cin.get();
cin.ignore();
```

I will recommend you using the second method because its plateform dependent.

> It's frowned upon because it's a platform-specific hack that has nothing to do with actually learning programming, but instead to get around a feature of the IDE/OS - the console window launched from Visual Studio closes when the program has finished execution, and so the new user doesn't get to see the output of his new program.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably working just fine. Once it receives the input it runs through the rest of your code and then exits. You need to put a pause statement in on the end - something like

```c
system("Pause");
```

or

```c
cin.get();
```